# enable metered APIs and services in MS Graph: Microsoft Azure New-AzResourceGroup cmd line error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a link Microsoft.GraphServices/Accounts Azure resource to link a metered third party API to MS TEAMS, and following the instruction on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/metered-api-setup.
The command, and the error messages are below.

```
New-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName myRG1 -Name myGraphAppBilling --resource-type Microsoft.GraphServices/accounts --properties  "{`"0000.1111.2222..`": `"myAppGUID`"}" --location Global --subscription mySubscriptionGUID
```

The error message is:

> New-AzResourceGroup : cannot bind the parameter because parameter 'Name' is specified more thna once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax.For example, 'parameter value1, value2..'

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Make a link between 3rd party metered application's API and MS TEAMS logs/archives in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

> The error occured as you specified **`-Name`** parameter twice and included parameters in **wrong format** by mixing CLI command with PowerShell.

When I ran same command as you, I got **same error** like below:

```
New-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName myRG1 -Name myGraphAppBilling --resource-type Microsoft.GraphServices/accounts --properties "{`"3499fc76-83ed-41ce-xxxxxxxxxxx`": `"myAppGUID`"}" --location Global --subscription 124c97c3-58a7-4eb5-axxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you can follow below steps by running these PowerShell commands:

Initially, register ***Microsoft.GraphServices*** provider with this command:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.GraphServices
```

**Response:**

[image]

You need to wait for few minutes till `RegistrationState` becomes **Registered** like below:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.GraphServices
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, create one new **resource group** using below command:

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name myRG -Location EastUS
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below PowerShell command,  Azure resource of type **"Microsoft.GraphServices/accounts"** created successfully like below:

```
New-AzResource -ResourceName myGraphAppBilling -ResourceGroupName myRG -ResourceType Microsoft.GraphServices/accounts -Properties @{"appId"="3499fc76-83ed-41ce-ac33-xxxxxxxx"} -Location Global -Force
```

**Response:**

[image]